# How to configure STM32 CAN filters in ID List mode?

Tags: filter, stm32, can-bus, hal

I need to configure filters in STM32F103 in ID List mode. I can configure it in Mask Mode. There is a example configuration code for Mask Mode:

```c
sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x10<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0xff<<5; 
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sFilterConfig);
```

And it's working fine, I can receive messages with ID 0x10. But I need also to configure any filters in ID List mode. There is the code I try to use, but it doesn't work:

```c
sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 1;
sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh  = 0x10<<5;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sFilterConfig);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "<< 5" expression below should work (assuming RTR,IDE and EXTID[17:15] all 0):
sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT